# Не выполняются клики модулем pyautogui/ahk и даже pydirectinput

Tags: python, pyautogui, autohotkey

Пишу пайтон скрипт для автоматизации рутинных действий, и не один из модулей перечисленных выше не выполняет клик в окне игры, но в браузере и на рабочем столе клики проходят. Проверял на ноутбуке все работает, переустанавливал все модули, не помогло, переустанавливал сам пайтон, тоже не помогло. Как можно попробовать ещё решить проблему?

Comment: Напишите название игры, чтобы можно было попробовать на своем компе. А так, стоит опробовать еще библиотеки ctypes, autopy, pywin32(win32api).

Comment: @Cowboyserg там абсолютно любая игра, будь это The Binding of Isaac Rebirth или эмулятор Андроида nox или Bluestack, ctypes попробовал не срабатывали так же, а вот win32api нормально работает